# Ajax envia post pero recibo get request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropzone

Hola estoy intentando enviar un post vía ajax , pero me esta llegando request de tipo get vació. 
Estoy en una instalación limpia de laravel 5.4 (para probar que nada este interfiriendo de algún modo).
este es mi código :

```
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/dropzone.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('/js/dropzone.js')!!}"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            Dropzoneeeee
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('image.store') }}" class="dropzone" id="dropzone" method="POST">

                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2,
        method:"POST",

        accept: function(file, done) {
          if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
            done("Naha, you don't.");
          }
          else { done(); }
        }
      };
    </script>
```

> las rutas en web.php:

```
    <?php


       Route::get('/', function () {
         return view('welcome');
       });


   Route::post('/image', ['as' => 'image.store', 'uses' =>  
   ImageController@store']);
```

> el controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que sale al ejecutar dd($request)?

Comment: @Jemonge   no muestra nada , el tema es que el metodo es post y me esta llegando un get , por lo que me tira un methodnotallowed exception. Si pongo un metodo get en el controlador , como puede ser index y dentro hago un dd , me muestra los datos del request pero todo vacio.

Comment: Veo que estás utilizando dropzone, tal vez esté haciendo algo mal. Qué pasa si el formulario lo envías con un botón submit? Sigue llegando Get?

Comment: Veo que tienes todo configurado como Post está raro que te llegue como Get.

Comment: @jemonge Con una funcion  $.post( )  me llega bien , el tema es el dropzone

Answer (score 1):

Forma correcta: (Considera todo tipo de imput y analiza los requires)

```
$(document).on("click",'[id^="proceso-save"]', function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    var req = 0;
    //formarea es el ID asignado al form generico que se utilizara para cargar todos los formulario
    var name = $("#formarea").attr("name");
    //analisamos si existen input con se requieren estar llenados.
    $('#formarea *').filter(':input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === "" && $(this).attr('required')){req ++;}
    });
    if(req == 0){
        //Metodo para crear y agregar un input mediante javascript y determinar el tipo de escenario que se ejecuta
        var input1 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "idprocess").val(id);
        var input2 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "idform").val(name);
        $('#formarea').append($(input1));
        $('#formarea').append($(input2));
        event.preventDefault();
        //Establecemos el form data
        var $form       = $("#formarea"),
            formData    = new FormData(),
            params      = $form.serializeArray();
        // Analisamos los Inputs Files tambien.
        var inputs = $("input:file[name^='i_file_']");
        $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
            // Prefix the name of uploaded files with "uploadedFiles-"
            // Of course, you can change it to any string
            var file = v.files[0];
            var name = $(v).attr("name");
            formData.append(name, file);
        });
        //agregamos cada parametro al FormData
        $.each(params, function(i, val) {
            formData.append(val.name, val.value);
        });
        //ejecutamos nuestra peticion Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            error: function(xhr,status,error){
                //en caso de errores lo soltamos por consola para la depuracion
                console.log(error);
            },
            success:    function(response) {
                // en caso de Guardado soltamos las respyesta del servidor en la caja de mensajes que estaba oculta
                $("#areasmg").html(response);
                $("#MsgArea").removeClass("").addClass("alert alert-warning alert-dismissable");
                $("#MsgArea").show();
                //Marcamos que el evento se ejecuto correctamente
                EventSuccess(id,name,'Se a Ejecutado Correctamente');
            }
        });
    }else{
        alert("Error: Debe llenar todos los Campo, Existen " + req + " campos vacios.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no estás enviando nada. Lo único que tienes es el token de verificación, por lo tanto la variable `$_REQUEST` no tendrás valores.

Si quieres enviar la imagen deberías crear un campo de tipo `file` y enviarlo, pero el campo lo dejas oculto.

Comment: Deberías far mejor formato a la respuesta: no ponerlo todo en mayúsculas (que son gritos en Internet), usar acentos, puntuar adecuadamente, etc. Además sería de gran ayuda si pudieras incluir un ejemplo del código que comentas funcionaría (p.e. ¿cómo sería ese campo de tipo `file` oculto?).